# Exibir dados ao clicar em link vindo do banco Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

Galera eu tenho a seguinte situação! Eu tenho uma lista de cadastros salva no meu banco Mongo, eu preciso exibir a lista coisa que eu ja fiz e quando clicar no produto abriria um tela com mais detalhes sobre aquele produto, sou novato em Mongo e estou tomando uma surra. No mysql eu apenas usaria um get pegava o id e pronto mais não consegui fazer em Mongo. Infelizmente não posso mudar o banco não tenho autorização logo preciso encontrar a solução. Estou usando PHP com Mongo.

Por exemplo eu tenho a lista,

Papel 
Borracha 
Caneta

Quando clicar em Papel preciso que abra uma tela exibindo todos os detalhes do material papel que esta cadastrado no banco como cor, tamanho etc. Dentro da tela de papel terá um botão denominado requisição. Quando apertar este botão abre uma pequeno formulário a ser preenchido com os campos nome e data, então quando clica em enviar preciso associar o nome desta pessoa ao item que ela pediu no caso papel.

Obs: Eu ja tenho o form ja estou listando o conteúdo, a única coisa que preciso ajuda é no processo de clicar no papel e exibir os detalhes, e na hora de enviar o form, relacionar o nome daquela pessoa com o item pedido.

Isso é o que estou usando para exibir a lista e quando eu clico neles sou levado para a pagina description.php mais obviamente aparecem todos os produtos com suas respectivas descrições uma vez que não especifiquei nada para individualiza-los. Ai esta meu primeiro problema.

```html
$rows = $mongo->executeQuery("empresa.produtos", $query);    
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "<a href=\"description.php\">$row->items<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Atualizando, eu usei um $id = $_GET['id']; comum como usaria se estivesse trabalhando com o Mysql. Quando a pessoa clica esta trazendo o id corretamente do item mais nao traz as outras informacoes. Eu so preciso trazer os outros campos.